# radius and angle Independent gaussian random variable, reverese mapping , help

Tags: random-variables

Consider the random point $(X,Y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The ratio $X/Y$ tells us what angle the segment from $(0,0)$ to $(X,Y)$ makes with the $x$-axis, while $X^2+Y^2$ tells us how far $(X,Y)$ is from $(0,0)$.

The distribution of $(X,Y)$ is symmetric under rotations, so the distribution of the angle $\Theta$ is uniform and independent of the radius $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$.

This intuitive explanation can be made more rigorous by converting to polar coordinates.

---

The joint density of two independent standard normals $(X,Y)$ is 
$$f(x,y)={1\over 2\pi} \exp(-(x^2+y^2)/2).$$ Converting to polar coordinates 
we get the  joint density of $(R,\Theta)$ as
$$g(r,\theta)={r\over 2\pi}\exp(-r^2/2)={1\over 2\pi}\cdot r\exp(-r^2/2).$$
This product form of $g(r,\theta)$ shows that $\Theta$  and $R$ are independent.

I don't understand how to map it backwards, that is get the gaussian random variable from the radium and angle pdf ?

Comment: $(X,Y)=(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$.

Answer (score 3):

$(X,Y)=(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$

Comment: Can you please show me how I can substitute it into the independent pdf found ?

Comment: Go through the process of converting that you already went through, this time in the opposite direction. So again you need to find a Jacobian.

Comment: thank you, i found the answer, I just didn't know what a jacobian was till you mentioned it.